# C++ multidimension array storing strings

Tags: c++, arrays

I wish to store for example 10 words into a multi-d array. This is my code.

```
char array[10][80]; //store 10 words, each 80 chars in length, get from file
int count = 0;
while ( ifs >> word ){ //while loop get from file input stream <ifstream>
  array[count++][0] = word;
}
```

when i compile, there's error. "invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ ". ifs return a char pointer. How can i succesffuly store into array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is C++, I would use the STL containers to avoid some `char*` limitations. `word` would have type `std::string`, `array` would have type `std::vector<std::string>` and you would `push_back` instead of assigning. The code looks like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string word;
std::vector<std::string> array;
while(ifs >> word) {
   array.push_back(word);
}
```

This is better than `char*` for a few reasons: you hide the dynamic allocation, you have words with real variable size(up to memory size), and you don't have any issues if you need more than 10 words.

**Edit**: as mentioned in the comments, if you have a compiler that supports C++11, you can use `emplace_back` and `std::move` instead, which will move the string instead of copying it (`emplace_back` alone will construct the string inplace.)

Comment: Why not `emplace_back`?

Comment: @Jefffrey in the remote possibility his compiler doesn't support C++11, `push_back` is necessary.

Comment: I feel I should assume the contrary though. For instance, the default in GCC 4.8 is not C++11. Can't say anything about other compilers though.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a pointer to array I think, that can access each value of array blocks one by one (or the way you want). You can also try dynamic allocation. Those are pointer things so then it'll be comparable easily.

Comment: Those are "pointer things", what does that mean? Also why are you suggesting dynamic allocation? Also, why use C-style arrays?

Answer (score 0):

word is char*(string), but array[count++][0] is store a char, you can change "array[count++][0] = word;" to "strcpy(array[count++], word);"

```
char array[10][80]; //store 10 words, each 80 chars in length, get from file
int count = 0;
while ( ifs >> word ){ //while loop get from file input stream <ifstream>
  strcpy(array[count++], word);
}
```

Comment: Congratulations in using the `C` part of `C++`.